# Writing a query where attribute value same as attriute name

Tags: mysql

here's my problem the following is my table schema

Table: Images

```
| id | title | width | height | span   | status |
| 1  | s1    | 900   | 310    | height | 1      |
| 2  | s2    | 300   | 250    | width  | 1      |
| 3  | s3    | 450   | 400    | width  | 1      |
| 4  | s4    | 650   | 560    | width  | 1      |
```

Under the column\attribute `span` as you can see i am keeping **width** or **height** while in the attributes under the attributes `width` or `height` i am keeping dimensions in number.

When i run this query

```
UPDATE `images` SET `span` =  width  WHERE `ID` = 1
```

OR

```
UPDATE `images` SET `span` = `width` WHERE `ID` = 1
```

what this does is that it selects the value of attribute `width` of the record and replaces the value of attribute 'span' with it. Here are the changes made by this query

Table: Images

```
| id | title | width | height | span   | status |
| 1  | s1    | 900   | 310    | 900    | 1      |
| 2  | s2    | 300   | 250    | width  | 1      |
| 3  | s3    | 450   | 400    | width  | 1      |
| 4  | s4    | 650   | 560    | width  | 1      |
```

while all i wanna do is replace the value of span at record 1 with this text **width**

same problem happens when i use the text name height.

**WHAT TO DO?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your are using backticks  on your string to apply to a field while you are supposed to use quotes `'`

```
UPDATE `images` SET `span` = 'width' WHERE `ID` = 1
                             ^here ^ you need quotes
```

You can avoid using quotes for your `ID` column since it should be an integer column but you cannot avoid using them where column is not integer (as your first example)  `span =  width`

Backtick are normally used for column name as well as table name, but they can be avoided as far as you will not use any `reserved keyword`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but can't you just do: UPDATE `images` SET `span` = images.width WHERE `ID` = 1